# How to numerically create a Delone set, $Del(r, R)$, in a square box in Euclidean space?

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, computational-mathematics

I want to numerically create a Delone set, $Del\,(r, R)$, in a square box in Euclidean space. I was successful in creating a set of points which are at least $2*r$ distance away from each other. But the next challenge is to make sure that there's no empty sphere of radius $R$ in the box. I am unable to find an algorithm to successfully satisfy this condition.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thank you. I edited the question.